# Unable to find JAVA icon in System-Preference or Library of my MAC

Tags: java, macos, java-11

I have been a Windows user all my life and have recently got a MAC. My Mac is using MacOS Catalina. 
I am trying to set-up JDK and get going on a project, however the issue is after I have installed JDK 11.0.4, I don't see any Java-icon on my system preference nor could I find Java folder in my ~library. However, when I go to terminal and do *java -version* I do see java being present as below

```
~ % java -version
java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I need help to see how I can resolved this, and then add my java installed location to my **.bash_profile**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after hunting around for a while I have figured the following out:

1. You won't get JAVA in your Mac's *System Preference* until you have added JAVA home directory in your bash profile, irrespective of the java version installed
2. Generally be default Java gets installed in your **MacintoshHD**
3. So, open your MacintoshHD & then go to **GO** option from your Finder
4. Next click on **Go to folder** option and type-in *~/Library*
5. Now you will see a **Java** folder and under that **JavaVirtualMachines**
6. You will now have JDK folder of whichever java version installed
7. Right click on JDK folder and click on info, copy the 'Where' location
8. Open your bash profile with following command **vi .bash_profile**
9. Once in VI editor, insert the following:

export JAVA_HOME=copied Where location from JDK folder followed by /Contents/Home

It should look something like below
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home

10. Now quit editor by **:wq** and restart your machine and you will now have JAVA in your system preference.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Check your  JDK version: `/usr/libexec/java_home` or e.g., `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` for Java 7. Configure it in `~/.bashrc` with `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`
JDKs are under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ for example in
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 1):

Normally the JDK is located under 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

The AdaptOpenJdk for example is located here: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk`

Comment: I don't have a folder as Java under /Library/

Comment: depends which Java installation you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that are still struggling with it. Here is the thing.

> The Java Preferences app was part of Apple Java installation and is not used by Oracle Java. Therefore, OS X releases from Apple that do not include Apple Java will not include Java Preferences.

["What happened to the Java Preferences app in Application -> Utilities?"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_install_faq.html#osxfaq_java_pref_app)